# Manipulation of equation into quadratic form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, recreational-mathematics, quadratic-forms

I am reading a paper for self study, and am trying to figure out how the authors can make the following claim.  They claim the following statements are equivalent:

$$\frac{c{\sqrt{d_1+d_2}}-\sqrt{d_1}z_1 -\delta(d_2) \sqrt{P_0P_1}}{\sqrt{d_1+d_2}} =  -z_{\beta}$$

and

$$(\delta^2p_1p_0)d_2^2 - d_2[(c+z_\beta)^2 -2\sqrt{d_1p_1p_0}z_1\delta] + d_1[z_1^2 - (c+z_{\beta})^2] =0$$

How do we rearrange the first equation so that it is a quadratic function of $d_2$?  Any hints would be appreciated!  I have tried multiplying both sides by $\sqrt{d_1+d_2}$ then squaring, and that didn't work.  Somehow I need to multiply $z_\beta$ by $c$, and I can't see when in the derivation that needs to happen.  Thank you!

[Here](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/16022174/) is the paper for reference.

Comment: It looks to me that you can first split off the first term in the fraction's numerator, to get $$c - \frac{\sqrt{d_1}z_1 +\delta(d_2) \sqrt{P_0P_1}}{\sqrt{d_1+d_2}} =  -z_{\beta}$$. Rearrange to put $c+z_{\beta}$ on one side, then squaring and some more rearranging should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance, it seems that the difficulty lies in the combination of terms that contain $d_2$ and $\sqrt{d_1+d_2}$ in the numerator, because if you simply square the expression, the two factors will mix, and you won't be able to get rid of the square root over $\sqrt{d_1 + d_2}$ in the mix term. However, note that the denominator itself is $\sqrt{d_1+d_2}$, so you can split off the term $c\sqrt{d_1+d_2}$ in the numerator, and then the left hand side becomes,
$$
\frac{c\sqrt{d_1+d_2} - z_1\sqrt{d_1} - d_2 \delta\sqrt{p_1p_0}}{\sqrt{d_1 + d_2}} = \frac{c\sqrt{d_1+d_2}}{\sqrt{d_1+d_2}} - \frac{z_1\sqrt{d_1}+d_2\delta\sqrt{p_1p_0}}{\sqrt{d_1+d_2}}\ .
$$
This allows you to rearrange the equation into
$$
\frac{z_1\sqrt{d_1} + d_2 \delta\sqrt{p_1p_0}}{\sqrt{d_1+d_2}} = c + z_\beta
$$
and further into
$$
z_1\sqrt{d_1} + d_2 \delta\sqrt{p_1p_0} = (c+z_\beta)\sqrt{d_1+d_2}\ .
$$
Now you can square both sides and rearrange it into a quadratic equation in $d_2$.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you so much!